# How to declare global variable in c#

Tags: visual-studio, global-variables

I am trying to define user type (Admin or normal user ) through all of my app (classes and forms) 
So I need to create a global variable that will use its value to check what features should be available to that user
How is it done, and is it a good idea

Comment: It's not a good idea, that's why people don't do it. However, going into the different patterns to use instead is really more of a book than a post here. Just grab your favorite book, it *will* have a chapter on global variables and why it's not a good idea to use them.

Comment: That's the only idea I can think of, otherwise, I'll have to call a verify function each time I open another form for example

Comment: Well, you don't need to think of anything. You don't need to reinvent programming from the ground up. Plenty of people have done before and most of them wrote books about it. So go get a good book on the topic of programming whatever you program (WPF MVVM maybe?) and I guarantee it will explain it. But to write an answer here that encompasses *all possible options and framework you may or may not be using* is **way** too broad. That's why books still sell. They can provide information targeted at whatever you are doing.